# Database or List of latitudes,longitudes and time zone for different cities in world

Tags: timezone, location

I need to create a mysql database for different cities in the world with following details

- Longitude
- Latitude
- City
- Time Zone

I have tried lots of search results and found [Geolite](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geolite)

As the database contains nearly **400 thousand** records, i am afraid to save those data in my database.Also time zone is not there with this list.

Is there any online **API/XML** to get the details by passing city name to get details or do i have to use the geolite data to saved in my database.
Thanks you.

Comment: See [this community wiki entry](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16086962/634824)